# python open csv search for pattern and strip everything else

Tags: python, python-3.x

I got a csv file 'svclist.csv' which contains a single column list as follows:

```
pf=/usr/sap/PL5/SYS/profile/PL5_D00_s4prd1
pf=/usr/sap/PL5/SYS/profile/PL5_ASCS01_s4prdascs
```

I need to strip each line from everything except the PL5 directoy and the 2 numbers in the last directory
and should look like that

```
PL5,00
PL5,01
```

I started the code as follow:

```
clean_data = []
with open('svclist.csv', 'rt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.__contains__('profile'):
        print(line, end='')
```

and I'm stuck here.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the regular expression - (PL5)[^/].{0,}([0-9]{2,2})

For explanation, just copy the regex and paste it here - 'https://regexr.com'. This will explain how the regex is working and you can make the required changes.

```
import re
test_string_list = ['pf=/usr/sap/PL5/SYS/profile/PL5_D00_s4prd1',
                    'pf=/usr/sap/PL5/SYS/profile/PL5_ASCS01_s4prdascs']

regex = re.compile("(PL5)[^/].{0,}([0-9]{2,2})")
result = [] 
for test_string in test_string_list:
    matchArray = regex.findall(test_string)
    result.append(matchArray[0])
with open('outfile.txt', 'w') as f:
    for row in result:
        f.write(f'{str(row)[1:-1]}\n')
```

In the above code, I've created one empty list to hold the tuples. Then, I'm writing to the file. I need to remove the () at the start and end. This can be done via str(row)[1:-1] this will slice the string.
Then, I'm using formatted string to write content into 'outfile.csv'

Comment: thank you very much for you answer.
it helped me in most of the problem
but apparently I didn't explain my dilemma very good.
the PL5 is also a variable of composite of 3 characters which can be any digits and capital letters.
i'm trying to figure it up by myself but if you can help to finish it, it will be helpful :)

Comment: @Barak That's easy to do. You just need to modify the regex. I'll wait for today to let you try by yourself. :). Use the site that I provided for explanation. For debugging regex use - 'https://www.debuggex.com' . Change the language to python and at the top, you'll see the option to copy code snippet which can be used to copy the regex code directly.

Comment: i was able to do get the results thanks to your guldens.now i'm stuck on the results 
`[('H4C', '96')]
[('TST', '34')]
[('6ER', '04')]
[('PL5', '00')]
[('PL5', '01')]`
I can't break it to 2 columns to a csv file :(
any thoughts on that?

Comment: Yup. That's also very easy to do. 1 question - are you writing the output to the CSV file?

Comment: yes I do write to a csv.
although i can continue using it in memory for further use

Comment: I'll update my ans for you. Just change the regex with your regex. :)

Comment: Done @Barak. Let me know if you're facing any issues while understanding the code.

Comment: i changed the last line to `f.write(f'{str(row)[2:-2]}\n')`
output is 'H4C', '96
TST', '34
6ER', '04
PL5', '00
PL5', '01
`
i need also removing the ' chars as well :)

again, thank you nvery much for all the help

Comment: managed to solve it  with pandas :)
I'm sure there is more elegant way of doing this but for now it's doing the job :)
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex for this, (in general, when trying to extract a pattern this might be a good option)

```py
import re
pattern = r"pf=/usr/sap/PL5/SYS/profile/PL5_.*(\d{2})"

with open('svclist.csv', 'rt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if 'profile' in line:
            last_two_numbers = pattern.findall(line)[0]
            print(f'PL5,{last_two_numbers}')
```

This code goes over each line, checks if "profile" is in the line (this is the same as _*contains*_), then extracts the last two digits according to the pattern

Answer (score 0):

I made the assumption that the number is always between the two underscores. You could run something similar to this within your for-loop.

```
test_str = "pf=/usr/sap/PL5/SYS/profile/PL5_D00_s4prd1"

test_list = test_str.split("_")  # splits the string at the underscores

output = test_list[1].strip(
    "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" + str.swapcase("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"))  # removing any character

try:
    int(output) # testing if the any special characters are left
    print(f"PL5, {output}")
except ValueError:
    print(f'Something went wrong! Output is PL5,{output}')
```